# Why can I not see a Postgres table owned by someone else when I do \dt?

Tags: postgresql

I have two roles in my postgres instance: **role1** and **role2**.

I run the following set of commands as super user.

```
GRANT CREATE on DATABASE database1 TO role1;
\c database1;
SET ROLE role1;
CREATE SCHEMA schema1;
SET ROLE "user who is super user";
GRANT USAGE on SCHEMA schema1 TO role2;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema1 TO role2;
```

I then use role1 to create tables in schema schema1. The owner of the tables is role1.

For some reason, when I execute \dt on the database1 as role2, I don't see any tables. Shouldn't I see the tables in schema1 since I have all privileges on all tables?